# f is a differentiable function with $f'(x) \geq a$. Prove that for each r>0, we have $f(r) \geq f(0) + ar$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

I'm unsure how to start this proof. The textbook I'm using is Apostol's Calculus, vol 1.

Comment: Use Mean Value Theorem .

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is differentiable then it is continuous and hence Riemann-integrable and moreover

$$
\int_0^r f'(x)\,\mathrm dx\geq\int_0^r a\,\mathrm dx\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad f(r)-f(0)\geq ar.
$$

Answer (score 0):

By MVT, $\frac{f(r)-f(0)}{r-0}=f'(c_r)\geq a.$ Can you finish from here?